# java: Which one to use as reference type when a class extends and also implements

Tags: java, reference

For example i have class which extends and also implements

```
public class Child extends Parent implements SomeInterface
{

}
```

Q1: So can i do both of the following

```
SomeInterface childObject = new Child();

and also

Parent p = new Child();
```

Q2: Which is generally preffered `interface` of `parent class` for reference type and why

Why i am asking is that i found the following code in android

```
RecyclerView rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.someview);
```

I am thinking to refer using superclass or interface (which I read is a good way of coding as per OOP design)

So i doing it as below

```
View rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.someview);
```

But i found `View` is Super class and not interface. I read its better to do `programming for the interfaces`.

Comment: Have you considered that `Parent` and `SomeInterface` can have different functions?

Comment: I agree, this isn’t about what is preferred but about what the use case is and what functionality you need to access.

Comment: There is no answer for all cases. It depends on the context. Think what exactly you want to achieve. If you have no clear plan that you will use particular code for multiple implementations of the same class or interface, don't use them. Instead, use your particular class. Only when you see a necessity to use some code for multiple subclasses of for all implementations of some intetrfaces, only then it makes sense to use this base class or interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, as you said you should avoid using (implementation/child) class as a reference as much as you can and always depend on (parent/interface) reference especially for your method parameters and instance variables.

considering which one should you choose, this will depend on which type of functionalities (methods) you will gonna use and whether it's included in the interface or the parent class.

also as a rule of thumb always use interface reference whenever it's possible.